# Work out % of time elapsed based on epoch

Tags: sql, sql-server

My DB lists SQL server jobs, their start times and average duration run times. I have the start time and ETA finish time showing as Epoch currently:

```
DATEDIFF(SECOND, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(minute,AVG(datediff(minute, p3.[Started], p3.Finished)),MAX(p3.[Started]))),  DATEADD(minute,AVG(datediff(minute, p3.[Started], p3.Finished)),MAX(p3.[Started]))) [ETAEpoch],
DATEDIFF(SECOND, CONVERT(date, GETDATE()), GETDATE()) [CurrentEpoch]
```

However I'd like to work out as a percentage how far along the job is to completion. Simple maths would suggest I take the current time divided by the ETA finish time, multiplied by 100 to get this.
Calculating it gives an accurate number, however SSMS shows '0' when I execute this:

```
DATEDIFF(SECOND, CONVERT(date, GETDATE()), GETDATE())
       /
       DATEDIFF(SECOND, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(minute,AVG(datediff(minute, p3.[Started], p3.Finished)),MAX(p3.[Started]))),  DATEADD(minute,AVG(datediff(minute, p3.[Started], p3.Finished)),MAX(p3.[Started])))
```

I'm pretty sure there's something that needs to come off/change in order for this sum to work but I can't figure out what!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server does integer division.  So, 1/2 is 0 not 0.5.  So, you need to convert to a format that has decimal places.  I often do this just by multiplying by `1.0`:

```
(DATEDIFF(SECOND, CONVERT(date, GETDATE()), GETDATE()) * 1.0 /
 DATEDIFF(SECOND, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(minute,AVG(datediff(minute, p3.[Started], p3.Finished)),MAX(p3.[Started]))),  DATEADD(minute,AVG(datediff(minute, p3.[Started], p3.Finished)),MAX(p3.[Started]))
)
```

Comment: Perfect thanks! I think my calculation for the ETA Epoch is way off as it's calculating that % really low

Comment: @danverbs . . . That is possible.  You can ask another question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Figured it out... the average was working out DATEDIFF in minutes... changed them all over to seconds and it's working out correctly now. Thanks again for your help :)